# How are instructions and data stored in memory?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I am debugging a C# program and the disassembly view show this:

> 0x006E2813  pop         ebx
>   0x006E2814  pop         esi

So `pop ebx` is stored in 1 byte(in one single address), but how can that be since the `pop` instruction itself is 1 byte large?

Or it shows only the data(`ebx`), so where are the instructions stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can that be since the pop instruction itself is 1 byte large?

It's encoded to different bytes depending on which register it uses. `pop ebx` is 0x5B, `pop esi` is 0x5E. There are many websites and manuals documenting the x86 instruction encoding.

Comment: Assembly language generally uses bytes as operands to hold "immediate" values, values that are a memory location, or values that are pointer to it.  Registers don't live in memory, and x86 doesn't have enough registers to make using even an 8-bit byte completely efficient for referencing a register (you'd have a lot of wasted bits), so it makes sense to encode them as part of the instruction.